# AES/Rijndael in C++ Microsoft CryptoAPI

Tags: c++, vb.net, encryption, cryptoapi, mscapi

How can I convert the following cryptography code (VB.NET 4.0) to the C++ equivalent one, using Microsoft CryptoAPI (CryptDeriveKey, BCrypt[...] functions, CryptAcquireContext, etc.)? (I haven't found a single article on the Internet describing AES using Microsoft CryptoAPI...)

```
Dim Key(31) As Byte
Dim IV(15) As Byte

Array.Copy(SomeByteArray, IV, 16)
Array.Copy((New SHA512Managed).ComputeHash(SomeByteArray), Key, 32)

Using AESEncr As New RijndaelManaged() With {.Padding = PaddingMode.ISO10126}

    FinalEncrypted = AESEncr.CreateEncryptor(Key, IV).TransformFinalBlock(AnotherByteArray, 0, AnotherByteArray.GetLength(0))

End Using
```

and the decrypting one:

```
Dim Key(31) As Byte
Dim IV(15) As Byte

Array.Copy(SomeByteArray, IV, 16)
Array.Copy((New SHA512Managed).ComputeHash(SomeByteArray), Key, 32)

Using AESEncr As New RijndaelManaged() With {.Padding = PaddingMode.ISO10126}

    FinalDecrypted = AESEncr.CreateDecryptor(Key, IV).TransformFinalBlock(FinalEncrypted, 0, FinalEncrypted.GetLength(0))

End Using
```

(Note: I already have C++ code about the SHA-512 method, so don't bother with that.)

Comment: If you don't mind we would like you to try yourself, get back if you get stuck somewhere.

Comment: Start reading [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380256(v=vs.85).aspx), then write some code and see what happens.

Comment: @owlstead I found how to use CNG BCrypt.dll, but: 1) It doen't support Windows XP, which the above .NET code does, 2) It doesn't support custom key/iv lengths (properties BCRYPT_OBJECT_LENGTH and BCRYPT_BLOCK_LENGTH are read-only) and 3) It doesn't support setting a custom key from a byte array (I assume so, as I read [this code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18713/Simple-way-to-crypt-a-file-with-CNG)). So, what can I do to tackle all of the above problems? (abandoning the XP platform is NOT an option for me...)

Comment: @owlstead I cannot find any ALG_ID for AES with key length 32-bytes, only 128-bytes+ (as far as advapi32's functions (CryptAcquireContext, etc.) are considered and with [the above comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25609064/aes-rijndael-in-c-microsoft-cryptoapi#comment40026703_25609064) I showed that bcrypt functions are useless, so I think that no option is left)...

Comment: Try [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386979%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for starters

Comment: @owlstead Didn't you read my comments? I said that it is impossible to have key length = 32 bytes and IV length = 16 bytes. Microsoft CryptoAPI only supports 128 bytes+ (key lengths) [THIS LINK](). And I am really NOT a starter! READ MY CODE: `Dim Key(31) As Byte         Dim IV(15) As Byte`...

Comment: Maybe you are really not a starter in VB/C++, but you are requesting *us* to give you an example *using MS CryptoAPI*, for which you are adamant that it does not support AES-256 (only in the comments). I don't know about your C++ skills but above makes it pretty clear you are a starter with regards to asking questions here.

Comment: @owlstead Oh, I am VERY SORRY!!! I misunderstood AES-256... It is 256 **BITS** key length. I thought it was 256 bytes! Maybe I should have paid more attention to [the comments section that clearly says "key length: 256 bits"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)! So, 256 bits = 32 bytes, just as I wanted... OK, it will be easy to produce code for that, I will return with full code... CALG_AES_256 is what I want. (So, I am a starter to paying attention to what I am reading)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the code I made for AES-256 Encryption/Decryption is the following: (it takes `BYTE* Data` and `BYTE* IV` as parameters)

```
    BYTE *hash, *res;
    HCRYPTPROV hCrypt = NULL;
    HCRYPTKEY hKey = NULL;

    struct {
        BLOBHEADER hdr;
        DWORD len;
        BYTE key[32];
    } key_blob;

    key_blob.hdr.bType = PLAINTEXTKEYBLOB;
    key_blob.hdr.bVersion = CUR_BLOB_VERSION;
    key_blob.hdr.reserved = 0;
    key_blob.hdr.aiKeyAlg = CALG_AES_256;
    key_blob.len = 32;

    hash = ComputeSHA512Hash(IV);
    copy(hash, hash + 32, key_blob.key);

    res = new BYTE[16];
    copy(Data, Data + 15, res);
    res[15] = 0;

    // Get the Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Service Provider

    if (!CryptAcquireContext(&hCrypt, NULL, MS_ENH_RSA_AES_PROV, PROV_RSA_AES, 0))
        throw E_FAIL;

    // Import our key blob

    if (!CryptImportKey(hCrypt, (BYTE *)&key_blob, sizeof(key_blob), NULL, 0, &hKey))
        throw E_FAIL;

    // Set the mode to Cipher Block Chaining

    DWORD dwMode = CRYPT_MODE_CBC;

    if (!CryptSetKeyParam(hKey, KP_MODE, (BYTE *)&dwMode, 0))
        throw E_FAIL;

    // Set the Initialization Vector to ours

    if (!CryptSetKeyParam(hKey, KP_IV, IV, 0))
        throw E_FAIL;

    // Do the main encryption

    DWORD pdwDataLen = 15;

    if (!CryptEncrypt(hKey, NULL, TRUE, 0, res, &pdwDataLen, 16))
        throw E_FAIL;

    // Do the main decryption

    pdwDataLen = 16;

    if (!CryptDecrypt(hKey, NULL, TRUE, 0, res, &pdwDataLen))
        throw E_FAIL;

     // Destroy whatever was created before (free memory)

     delete hash;

     delete res;

     if (hKey)
            CryptDestroyKey(hKey);

     if (hCrypt)
            CryptReleaseContext(hCrypt, 0);
```

As I previously said, I already have code for the ComputeSHA512Hash() function, so my code is complete for my purposes. I hope this code will be useful for everyone wanting to write AES-256 code.